# How do I assign font-awesome under <script> tag?

Tags: font-awesome, nuxt.js

The problem is I dont know how to assign the font-awesome under `<script>` tag which I follow from the tutorial: https://dev.to/coolgoose/how-to-setup-font-awesome-5-as-vuecomponent-in-nuxtjs-54e4 . I have try to assign but it still not appear.

I have tried to assign with this code but still, the font awesome icon does not appear.

from this  code `<template>` tag

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fab', 'linkedin']" style="font-size: 22px" />
```

to this code under `<script>` tag

```
{ icon: 'fab fa-linkedin', text: 'Custom Order'},
```

The expected result that the font awesome under the `<script>` tag will be appear.

Comment: you need to do something with your `nuxt.config.js` file. You need to add it as a plugin.

Comment: yes sir, it works for under <template> file when I add the module in the nuxt.config.js but how the pattern that we use to assign in the javascript?

Comment: your icon attribute should just match what you did in template, i.e. `icon: ['fab', 'linkedin']`

Comment: yes i did this already but it not appear Sir. Wait I upload my code to codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem solves I have included the font inside the nuxt plugin. So the problem solve. Thanks, everybody.